# ControlsFX Notifications Exception

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, jar, controlsfx

I am using ControlsFX library for creating Notifications. When I launch project in IDE (NetBeans) everything is good, there is no exception. But when I  launch project from jar `java -jar <project>.jar` I have such exceptions like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyTq5.png).

**Code:**

```
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Notifications.create()
                    .title("Lorem")
                    .text("Ipsum")
                    .hideAfter(javafx.util.Duration.seconds(5))
                    .show();
        }
    });
```

P.S. Project was build with dependencies, also I tried to clean&build

N.B. Also in project I have another dependencies but there are no problems with launching them from jar

Comment: Are you trying to show the Notification using a thread?

Comment: @Sedrick, yeap (add code in header)

Comment: Are you using the same java version with Netbeans and from the console? Also please post the stacktrace as text (code block). (You can redirect the output to a file by using `java -jar <project>.jar 1> output.txt 2>&1`.)

Comment: @fabian, NetBeans - JDK8, Console - JDK9; Does it matter?

Comment: There are 2 different versions of ControlsFX for javafx 8 and for javafx 9(+?).

Comment: @fabian, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

According to [FX Experiance](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/), for **JDK8** you have to use lib with version **8.40.14** and for **JDK9-10** - **9.0.0**.

So, for **JDK 8u171** I choosed **8.40.14** and everything works great in both ways (from IDE and *.jar)